# Accessing a protected member of a base class

Tags: scala, inheritance, protected, companion-object

I'm not using inheritance that often, so i'm not really sure why it doesn't work. In my project i have the following stuff:

Base sealed class with protected member:

```
sealed class TheRoot {
  protected def some: String = "TheRoot"
}
```

And it's descendant with some logic:

```
final case class Descendant() extends TheRoot {
  def call: Unit = { 
    val self: TheRoot = this
    self.some // <<- throw compilation error
  }
}
```

Compiling above gives me the following error:

```
error: method some in class TheRoot cannot be accessed in TheRoot
 Access to protected method some not permitted because
 prefix type TheRoot does not conform to
 class Descendant where the access take place
           self.some
```

I'm not really sure what's the problem to call the protected member from the super class... But it's getting more interesting if we wrap it into companion object, it magically fixes the problem:

```
sealed class TheRoot {
  protected def some: String = "TheRoot"
}

object TheRoot {
  final case class Descendant() extends TheRoot {
    def call: Unit = {
      val self: TheRoot = this
      self.some // <<- NO ERROR!
    }
  }
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class TheRoot
defined object TheRoot
```

Answer (score 1):

As descripted in the [document](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/packages-and-imports.html)

> Access to protected members is also a bit more restrictive than in Java. In Scala, a protected member is only accessible from subclasses of the class in which the member is defined. In Java such accesses are also possible from other classes in the same package. In Scala, there is another way to achieve this effect, as described below, so protected is free to be left as is. The example shown illustrates protected accesses:

```
 package p {
  class Super {
    protected def f() { println("f") }
  }
  class Sub extends Super {
    f()
  }
  class Other {
    (new Super).f()  // error: f is not accessible
  }
}
```

In your code, if you change `self.some` to `some`, it will be ok.

while the companion object can access any members of its companion class, so the `Descendant` of object `TheRoot` can access the protected method of `some`

Comment: I need to upcast the type of the current object, my example is simplified. In your quote you also have `a protected member is only accessible from subclasses of the class`, that's the reason i'm asking, to me the `Descendant` is a subclass of `TheRoot`. I know the mechanics of companion objects, but it's not clear to me why it allows protected access in this case

Comment: Why would you need to upcast `this` to a supertype? You can use the subtype in any place that accepts the subtype (except contravariant arguments, of course)... Anyway, scoping your protected member to enclosing package (`protected[p] def some: String = ...`) should also work like your example with enclosing `Descendant` in an object.

Comment: @4lex1v sorry, I have misunderstood your question before. I found another strange thing. this.some works but self.some not